# VueJS .filter changes content of array when it should not

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, filter

So what I am trying to do is filter an array based on contents of another array so this is the code I have.

```
private get filteredArray() {
  const filteredArray = this.unfilteredArray;
  console.log(this.unfilteredArray);

  filteredArray = this.unfilteredArray.filter(
    (p) => this.filteredNumbers.includes(p)
  );
  return filteredArray;
}
```

So for example we have the 2 arrays with values

```
this.unfilteredarray = ["1", "2", "4", "3"]
this.filteredNumbers = ["2"]
```

`this.filteredNumbers` gets values from a multiple selection box so here the user selected `2` and for this it works the item that is returned from the function is an array `filteredArray` with the value `"2"`. But when I then choose another number to filter on so `this.filteredNumbers` looks like `["2", "3"]` then I still only get `filteredArray` with value `"2"` back when I expect to get `2 and 3` back. This seems to be because on the `console.log` I can see that when I choose an `filterNumber` for the second time the `unfilteredArray` only has the value `"2"` left in it when it should still hold all its original numbers 1-4. What am I missing here or should I do this in some other way?

EDIT: followup question to correct answer
So if i had an object that among all its props has 3 different arrays that i want to filter them all and then return the object itself with its filtered arrays. Kind of like this but this ofc doesnt work as it will mess up the original array. Or would i need 3 different get?

```
private get filteredObject() {
   this.object.unfilteredArray.filter(
    (p) => this.filteredNumbers.includes(p)
  );
   this.object.unfilteredArrayTwo.filter(
    (p) => this.filteredNumbers.includes(p)
  );
   this.object.unfilteredArrayThree.filter(
    (p) => this.filteredNumbers.includes(p)
  );
  return object;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`const filteredArray = this.unfilteredArray;` doesn't clone the array as you want it just references the array which will be overridden when you do :

```
  filteredArray = this.unfilteredArray.filter(
    (p) => this.filteredNumbers.includes(p)
  );
```

which means that `filteredArray`  and  `this.unfilteredArray` refer to the same data.

to avoid this just return the filtered array with creating a temporary one :

```
private get filteredArray() {
   return this.unfilteredArray.filter(
    (p) => this.filteredNumbers.includes(p)
  );
  
}
```